# How to define a static member of a template class?

Tags: templates, static, c++14

I have the following declaration inside my template class declaration:

```
template<typename T1>
class node{

public:
static const shared_ptr<node<T1>> null_sp2node;

};
```

I am not sure how I could define this static const member?

I tried

```
template<typename T1> static const shared_ptr<node<T1>>
node<T1>::null_sp2node = NULL;
```

But get the following compiler error:

```
error: 'static' can only be specified inside the class definition
```

What is the correct way of defining the static member in this instance?

Comment: Assuming the rest of your template code is inline, another option is to use a static singleton function to declare and define the static member. It comes with the cost of a (usually) lock-free "first time" check and an inlined function call, but avoids that pesky definition file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already said by the error message, remove the `static` keyoword when *defining* (as opposed to *declaring*) the `static` member `null_sp2node`:

```
template<typename T1> const shared_ptr<node<T1>>
node<T1>::null_sp2node = NULL;
```

The keyword `static` should be only used when *declaring* the `static` member inside the class definition (just as you did in the `node` class template's definition), but **not** when *defining* the member (i.e.: creating the storage for it).